# Accessing the $index of an ng-repeat element inside uib-dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to write an ng-repeat in which each element in it has a dropdown menu attached to it. Within that dropdown menu I want to have functions that act on that individual element, for which I need access to the index of that element. Here is the html I have:

```
    <div class="user" ng-repeat = "item in tParticipants">
            <div uib-dropdown>
                <button class="free-agent-dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
                    <li role="menuitem" ng-click="removeFromList($child.$index)">Remove From List</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <label>Checked In</label>
    </div>
```

Problem is, the dropdown menu apparently doesn't have access to $index. I get undefined when I run that. I've also tried $parent.$index and the same thing happens. Any Angular pros have an idea on what I can do to grab that index? Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all, should be `removeFromList($child,$index)` (`,` instead of `.`) - You can also pass `item` to that function because if you will sort the results then `$index` will reference to the sorted item, and not its actual location in the array

Comment: You should directly use $index in removeFromList method like this : 
`<li role="menuitem" ng-click="removeFromList($index)">Remove From List</li>`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I didn't think to just pass the entire item into the function. I changed it to this: `<li role="menuitem" ng-click="removeFromTournament(tParticipants.indexOf(item))">Remove From Tournament</li>` and the code worked. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove your list element than no need to use any function on ng-click , you can do as like below :

```
<div class="user" ng-repeat = "item in tParticipants">
            <div uib-dropdown>
                <button class="free-agent-dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
                    <li role="menuitem" ng-click="tParticipants.splice($index,1);">Remove From List</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <label>Checked In</label>
    </div>
```